# c# ef framework one to one mapping not working

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core, one-to-one

I am trying to map a one to one mapping using code first approach but I keep face an error that says inversepropertyattributes are not pointing to each other.

```
InversePropertyAttributes on navigation 'Scheduler' in entity type 'Configuration' and on navigation 'Configuration' in entity type 'Scheduler' are not pointing to each other.
```

I am using this documentation (https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-one-to-one-relationship-using-fluent-api-in-ef-core.aspx) but it's still not working. Where did I made a mistake in creating the onetoone relationship in EF framework?

This is my script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS configuration
(    
    id                          UUID            PRIMARY KEY,
    code                        TEXT            NOT NULL,
    name                        TEXT            NOT NULL,
    description                 TEXT            NOT NULL,
    scheduler_id                UUID  UNIQUE    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT scheduler_fk FOREIGN KEY(scheduler_id) REFERENCES scheduler(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scheduler
(
    id                  UUID            PRIMARY KEY,
    initiated_by        TEXT            NOT NULL
);
```

**DBContext.cs**

```
public virtual DbSet<Scheduler> scheduler { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Configuration> configuration { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
    modelBuilder.HasPostgresEnum<SourceDestinationEnum>();
    modelBuilder.HasPostgresEnum<HttpActionEnum>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Scheduler>(entity =>
    {
            entity.HasOne<Configuration>(o => o.Configuration)
                .WithOne(o => o.Scheduler)
                .HasForeignKey<Configuration>(sa => sa.SchedulerId);
    });
}
```

**Configuration.cs**

```
[Table("configuration", Schema = "public")]
public class Configuration
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public Guid ConfigurationId { get; set; }

    [Column("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Column("scheduler_id")]
    public Guid SchedulerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SchedulerId")]
    [InverseProperty("Configuration")]
    public Scheduler Scheduler { get; set; }
}
```

**Scheduler.cs**

```
[Table("scheduler", Schema = "public")]
public class Scheduler
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public Guid SchedulerId { get; set; }

    [Column("initiated_by")]
    public string InitiatedBy { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("MappingConfiguration")]
    public virtual Configuration Configuration { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: EF6 only supports 1-1 relationships where the primary key of the dependent table is also the foreign key. EF Core supports unique constraints and 1-1 relationships like this.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#one-to-one

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks for the link, it works now. Thank you.